# .NET Reflection - Retrieve a Property Without Knowing Its Name

Tags: vb.net, wcf, reflection

I've been given a collection of WCF services to use which are all the same, save for the way certain properties of the objects returned by the services are named. If I have services A, B, and C, they each return nearly identical objects except that the objects' properties have been changed to reflect the service from whence they came. So, service A returns an object called `responseA` with a property `responseA.AValidation` and B returns a similar object with a property called `responseB.BValidation.`

Now, as much as might like to make changes to the services, I can't. Which means I'm stuck writing the exact same code for each service all to check for various possible error conditions,

```
If responseA.AErrors.Length > 0
...
If responseB.BErrors.Length > 0
...
and so on
```

What I'd love is to write one generic class that can use any of these services and has a single method to perform the above checking on any of them However, I'm stumped on how to check the value of a property when the name of that property can be slightly different from class to class.

So, is it possible to return the value of a property that I don't know the name of until runtime?

Here's what I've tried so far

```
Dim responseType As Type = responseA.GetType()

For Each Prop In responseType.GetProperties()
 If Prop.Name.Contains("ErrorInfoTypes") Then
  Dim errorTypes()
  errorTypes = Prop.GetValue(GetType(Array), Nothing)
  If errorTypes.Length > 0 Then
   'Deal with the fact there are errors.
  End If
  Exit For
 End If
Next
```

This complies, but `.GetProperties` returns no properties. What am I missing?

Comment: I would instead create a function that returns the value. Ex: ResponseHelper.GetErrors(responseA). You could hardcode, put the properties in a list of strings or guess the name. Are you sure it's a property and not just a public variable?

Comment: @the_lotus OMG!They are fields. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.